# How can I adjust the height of a sub-dropdown menu with CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, height, submenu

I am new and teaching myself slowly...I wanted to try to write a dropdown menu, but I noticed my submenu has extra height on the first child. I have tried adjusting padding, margin, in a few places like with the menu bar, the main drop down; but honestly am lost. The more I try, read, and research the more lost I get. I think my previous coding like a parent code is blocking me, but I just can't quite figure it out. I think it is an easy fix too. Anyone want to explain what I did wrong? Greatly appreciated...

My CSS

```
.body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #91A3BD;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: abel;
}
    
.menu-bar {
    background: #1D3860;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: abel;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: 400;
}
    
.menu-bar ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 90px;
    list-style: none;
    color: #91A3BD;
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
    
.menu-bar ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #91A3BD;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
    
.menu-bar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #91A3BD;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.current, .menu-bar ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
    
.sub-menu1 {
    display: none;
}
        
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #1D3860;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
    
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul {
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul li {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
    
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
    
.sub-menu2 {
    display: none;
}
    
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul li:hover .sub-menu2 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: none;
    margin-left: 146px;
    margin-top: -59px;
    background: #1D3860;
    white-space: nowrap;
 
    
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul li:hover .sub-menu2 ul {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}   
    
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul li:hover .sub-menu2 ul li {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
    
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul li:hover .sub-menu2 ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

My HTML

````
  <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Über Uns</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Leonberger</a>
        <div class="sub-menu1">
        <ul><li><a href="#">Hündinnen</a></li>        
          <li><a href="#">Welpen</a>
                <div class="sub-menu2">
                    <ul><li><a href="#">Würfe A</a></li>
                    </ul></div></li>
          <li><a href="#">Notvermittlung</a></li>
        </ul></div></li>
   <li><a href="#">Golden Retriever</a>
        <div class="sub-menu1">
        <ul><li><a href="#">Hündinnen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rüde</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Welpen</a>
                <div class="sub-menu2">
                    <ul><li><a href="#">Würfe A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Würfe B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Würfe C</a></li>
                    </ul></div></li>
          <li><a href="#">Notvermittlung</a></li>
        </ul></div></li>
    <li><a href="#">Welpen</a>
        <div class="sub-menu1">
        <ul><li><a href="#">vor dem Kauf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Welpen Infos</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Garantie</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kosten</a></li>
        </ul></div></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Welpenschule</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seminare</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pension</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">empfohlene Bücher</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hundefutter</a></li>
        </ul></div></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul></div>``` 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQgPP.jpg
````

Comment: Your provided html seems not complete.

Comment: You did not share proper code snippet. Please update your question and share proper code so that some one might be able to help you.

Comment: 1. Please share the full code     2. It looks like your HTML is incorrect, so your might want to validate it before trying to style it.

Answer (score 0):

With Global `Selector *` I eliminate extra **margin** and **padding** which was one of the reasons for your code problem.

Then I gave **sub-menu1** and **sub-menu2** `position : absolute`.

And I adjusted their position from top to right and left. You can easily see the changes by looking at the code.

*Of course, this menu is not responsive and test it in full screen mode.*

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #91A3BD;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: abel;
}

.menu-bar {
  background: #1D3860;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: abel;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.menu-bar ul {
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  color: #91A3BD;
}

.menu-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #91A3BD;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 18px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.current,
.menu-bar ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sub-menu1 {
  border-top: 1px solid #dd3322;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
}

.menu-bar ul li .sub-menu1 ul li {
  display: block;
}

.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 {
  display: block;
  background: #1D3860;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 62px;
}

.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu1 ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.sub-menu2 {
  border-top: 1px solid #dd3322;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: -1000px;
}

.menu-bar ul li .sub-menu1 ul li .sub-menu2 ul li {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu1 ul li:hover .sub-menu2 {
  background: #1D3860;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 0px;
  right: -150px
}

.sub-menu1 ul li:hover .sub-menu2 ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.sub-menu1 ul li:hover .sub-menu2 ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Über Uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Leonberger</a>
      <div class="sub-menu1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Hündinnen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Welpen</a>
            <div class="sub-menu2">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Würfe A</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Notvermittlung</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Golden Retriever</a>
      <div class="sub-menu1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Hündinnen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rüde</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Welpen</a>
            <div class="sub-menu2">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Würfe A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Würfe B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Würfe C</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Notvermittlung</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Welpen</a>
      <div class="sub-menu1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">vor dem Kauf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Welpen Infos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Garantie</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kosten</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <div class="sub-menu1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Welpenschule</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Seminare</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pension</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">empfohlene Bücher</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hundefutter</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I went through and adjusted my CSS code's margin and padding plus changing the submenus' position to absolute - the first child now aligns with its parent perfectly.